# How do I STOP getting messages that say "X new items in your Stack Exchange inbox -- XXX The following items were added to your inbox...."

Tags: support, global-inbox

These messages are annoying.  I want them **gone**.  I am not trying to close my SE inbox, nor am I trying to block everything from SE.

Never mind why or what I'm "really" trying to accomplish.

Comment: Where are you getting these messages? Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: I'm getting them in my e-mail account that's attached to my SE account.  I know how to get a screenshot but I don't know how to attach it my question.

Comment: Oh that it's email is probably enough

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can manage your email settings here:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/email/settings/current

The different options should be self-explanatory.

Comment: So if I set Edit profile and settings > Edit email settings -> Inbox to Off that should do it?

Comment: Yeap, that should be it. I generally tun off any and all email notifiactions...

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can turn it off in your email settings under your profile. You can get there by clicking on your avatar